# Call 1 CSS Class on 2 HTML Elements with Different ID and Class Attributes

Tags: html, css

I have 2 HTML elements that are of the same type. One element has an ID of `thing1` the other has an ID of `thing2`. The class attributes for both of these elements are different as well.

I want both of these HTML elements to use 1 CSS class that I have written.

Is it possible for 2 elemnts with different ID and Class attributes to call the same CSS class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#thing1, #thing2 { css here }
```

Simply call both IDs.

or add another class...

```
.additional { css here }

<div id="thing1" class="something aditional"></div>

<div id="thing2" class="thingclass aditional"></div>
```

Comment: Okay, I just wasn't sure if that was possible and or the syntax of it.

Answer (score 0):

What elements?

If it's a `div`, style all `div` tags, etc.